# Default frameworks missing in Xcode 6 beta

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6

While creating a new project in "Xcode 6 beta", I noticed that there are no `frameworks` attached.

In Xcode 5.x, when we created a new project, we had the following frameworks linked by default:-

1. Foundation
2. CoreGraphics
3. UIKit
4. XCTest

The frameworks that are linked when you create a new `SingleViewController` project in `Xcode 5.x`
[image: Default Xcode 5.x frameworks]

The **MISSING** frameworks when you create a new `SingleViewController` project in `Xcode 6 beta`
[image: No default frameworks for Xcode 6 beta]

I do understand that this is a `beta` release of the `IDE`. But it will help if we come to know whether these frameworks are now linked internally?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't quote me on this, but I think they are indeed linked internally. Since if you look at the code, there's the `import UIKit` line and it doesn't give any errors (Swift project).

Comment: They are imported as modules and linked automatically. In fact you could do this in Xcode5.x as well (for system frameworks) provided that you set `Enable Modules` & `Link Frameworks Automatically` to `Yes` in `Apple LLVM 5.1 - Language - Modules` section on `Build Settings`

Comment: @LordZsolt you are correct. Foundation is automatically linked. You should make this into an answer.

Answer (score 4):

In Xcode 6, the default for new projects is to use the module system (introduced in Xcode 5) to automatically link any frameworks you reference in code via `import` (Swift) or `@import`/`#import` statements (ObjC). Because the project template contains code that imports Foundation and UIKit (and a test case target that imports XCTest), you get those frameworks linked automatically.

As Alladinian commented, there's a switch to enable or disable this in the project settings, so you can turn it on for old projects, too. (Or turn it off if it gives you trouble.). Once your frameworks are automatically linked, you don't need to put them in Linked Frameworks & Libraries anymore.

And if you want to start using other frameworks in your project, you don't need to add them I'm the project settings, either—just import MapKit or CloudKit or AVFoundation or whatever in your source code and they'll automatically get linked.